# Oracleのバックアップ計画について

Tags: oracle

Oracle 12cR2をコンテナデータベースだけ、高速リカバリ領域は使用せず、アーカイブログモードで運用しています。

そこで疑問なのですが、現行のバックアップ計画では毎晩深夜にフルバックアップを取得し、1時間毎にアーカイブREDOログファイルのバックアップを取得しているのですが、後者の必要性がわかりません。

アーカイブREDOログファイルはあくまでオンラインREDOログファイルのコピーであって、そこまで頻繁に、なおかつアーカイブREDOログファイルだけを個別に取得する意味があるのでしょうか。

せめてもう少し間隔を空けるか、数時間前とかならオンラインREDOログファイルだけでじゅんぶんリカバリ可能だと思うのですが。

質問していて思ったのですが、そこまで頻繁にアーカイブREDOログファイルのバックアップを取らなければいけないとなると、よっぽど更新が速く、多いようなシステムということでしょうか？8つREDOロググループで、メンバの多重化は行っていないようですが、1時間もあればオンラインREDOログファイルがすべて上書きされちゃって、アーカイブREDOログが溜まりまくるから1時間おきに消して取ってしてるのでしょうか。

本番環境の実機を確認することができないため、経験者の方がいらっしゃいましたらどう思われるか質問したく思いました。宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REDOログのバックアップはデータが失われる期間を短くすることが目的だと思います。
当然ですがフルバックアップを復元するとバックアップ時点の状態に戻ってしまいます。
フルバックアップ後の変更(CRUD)はREDOログファイルに記録されています。
フルバックアップを復元した後にREDOログファイルに記録された変更を適用することにより、REDOログファイルをバックアップした時点の状態に戻すことができると思います。
フルバックアップだけだと最悪１日前の状態に戻りますが、１時間毎のREDOログのバックアップがあれば最悪でも１時間前の状態に戻すことができるはずです。